# Getting keras compiled model loss function

Tags: keras, tf.keras

Is there any way to get the compiled model loss/metrics functions from the model object?

I need this to access the loss function from within a callback, where I have access to self.model, but I can't find a way to access the compiled loss.

Comment: I'm trying to the same, did you find a solution?

Answer (score 1):

In tensorflow 2.4, model.compiled_loss._losses returns the name of the loss function.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to view the loss function use `model.loss`

Using `model.compiled_loss._losses` will return a `LossFunctionWrapper` object which you can call, but cannot get any other information on.